# search in JSON file and return the value in to HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a search box, in this search box I search all rows and show results in  tag, after I select the result, the value will add to the search box. But it doesn't show in the HTML tag. in the following lines I share the codes.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $('#search').keyup(function(){
     $('#result').html('');
     $('#state').val('');
     var searchField = $('#search').val();
     var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
     $.getJSON('json/db.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
       if (value.InstrumentID.search(expression) != -1 || value.LVal18.search(expression) != -1 || value.LVal18AFC.search(expression) != -1 || value.LVal30.search(expression) != -1 || value.CompanyLVal18AFC.search(expression) != -1 || value.CompanyLVal30.search(expression) != -1) 
       {
        $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"> '+value.LVal30+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.LVal18AFC+'</span></li>');
       }
      });   
     });
    });
    
    $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {

     var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
     $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
     $("#result").html('');
    });

    
    $("#getValue").click(function(){
        console.log(value.LVal30);
    });
});
```

also, the JSON format is like :

```
[{ "InstrumentID": "IR0101", "LVal18": "AR", "LVal18AFC": "AR", "LVal30": "AR", "CompanyInstrumentID": "IRO101", "CompanyLVal18AFC": "AR", "CompanyLVal30": "AR" }, { "InstrumentID": "IRR1C0101", "LVal18": "Chadormalu-R", "LVal18AFC": "AB", "LVal30": "AB", "CompanyInstrumentID": "IRO0001", "CompanyLVal18AFC": "AB", "CompanyLVal30": "AB" } ]
```

and I have a simple input like the below:

```
<div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="getValue" >Chose</button>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" data-value >


    </div>
    <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
```

as you see in the picture the I get the result in the box, but nothing happens in the console!
[image: the result appear in bot I do not get any log in console.]

edit - adding error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script3.js:138)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.js:5429)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.5.1.js:5233)
```

line 138 of script3.js is :

```
console.log(value.LVal30);
```

Comment: Your code works .. Are you getting any error in console  ? Does that `click` event gets called ? Do console there and see

Comment: thank Swati, I update the topic and errors added to the question.

Comment: Why you are accessing it like this `console.log(value.LVal30);` value will be null as you are getting that `values` inside your ajax . Between what do you need to achieve here ? Also , you can simply use `$('#search').val()` to get value of same as  onclick of `li` you are getting the selected value and assigning it to input-box.

Comment: Is it possible to assign the value, which appears in the input, to a paragraph? for instance, below the input it shows: You successfully chose {value.LVal30} . or if it's null, the paragraph under the input shows: you do not choose any option.

Comment: Yes just get that value using `$('#search').val()` in some variable and then check `if($('#search').val() != null){//show that value}else{//show custom messge}`

Comment: thank you @Swati, You help me a lot, it works. Just one more question. is it possible to display LVal18 ? or since I select LVal30 in the <li> it shows me the  LVal30. I change the code to the following and it shows me the result : `$("#getValue").click(function(){ if($('#search').val() != null) { $("p").text($('#search').val()); }else{ $("p").text(" Ops! nothing! "); } });`

Comment: You mean the other value after split ? If yes ,here is working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/29eoLjuk .Check consoles .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Swati for help me to find the solution. By the following change in JS file the result appears:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $('#search').keyup(function(){
     $('#result').html('');
     $('#state').val('');
     var searchField = $('#search').val();
     var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
     $.getJSON('json/db.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
       if (value.InstrumentID.search(expression) != -1 || value.LVal18.search(expression) != -1 || value.LVal18AFC.search(expression) != -1 || value.LVal30.search(expression) != -1 || value.CompanyLVal18AFC.search(expression) != -1 || value.CompanyLVal30.search(expression) != -1) 
       {
    $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"> '+value.LVal30+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.LVal18AFC+'</span> | <span style="display: none !important">'+value.InstrumentID+'</span></li>');
       }
      });   
     });
    });
    
    $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {

     var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
     $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
     $("#result").html('');
    });

    
    $("#getValue").click(function(){
    if($('#search').val() != null && $('#search').val() != "" )
    {
        $("d").text($('#search').val().split(',')[0]);
        $("d1").text($('#search').val().split(',')[1]);
        $("d2").text($('#search').val().split(',')[2]);
    }else{
    $("d").text(" ");
    }
    });
});
```

and also defining d, d1, d2 tags in my HTML file. I would be able to show the search result in several tags. Thanks again @Swati

Answer (score 1):

You can try below method to filter JSON data.

```js
var data = [{ "InstrumentID": "IR0101", "LVal18": "AR", "LVal18AFC": "AR", "LVal30": "AR", "CompanyInstrumentID": "IRO101", "CompanyLVal18AFC": "AR", "CompanyLVal30": "AR" }, { "InstrumentID": "IRR1C0101", "LVal18": "Chadormalu-R", "LVal18AFC": "AB", "LVal30": "AB", "CompanyInstrumentID": "IRO0001", "CompanyLVal18AFC": "AB", "CompanyLVal30": "AB" } ]

var searchterm="Company";
var result = data.filter(item=> {
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  var found= keys.filter(key=> {
    if (item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchterm) != -1) {
      return item;
    }
  });
  return ((found && found.length >0) ? true : false);
})
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Once you get the data.Loop through it and show it in you HTML like below.

```
result.map(value=> {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"> '+value.LVal30+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.LVal18AFC+'</span></li>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Vimal, Since my JSON file have more than 2400 item and it will update regularly, I have to load JSON file in my javascript. As you see the value shows in the <input>, I am wondering is it possible to mention this value in the paragraph under the input? for instance, it says; You successfully choose {LVal30} or if it is null, it just says: you do not select anything yet.

Comment: Replace above code inside your ajax call success callback. Json data I have only added for sample.

Comment: Can you please clear your requirement little more. I am not getting it. After search you want to display the result only, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, after search completed and the user chose the result, I want to show the result in another tag. the process is like that: 1- search in the input -2- select item in the list -3- click on the button - 4- the result appears under the input.